# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule and Tier Price

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon, tierprice

Here's what I am trying to achieve.

1. I have some products which have tiered pricing set for them. When purchasing one unit of such an item the regular price will apply. Whenever buying two units of such an item the price will drop. Whenever buying three units of such an item the price will drop even more.
2. I also have set a Shopping Cart Price Rule which will give customers a 10% discount whenever they use the coupon code "GIVEME10".
3. I don't want this discount to apply to products with tiered pricing, at least not when 2 or more units of such an item are purchased, since the customer will already get a discount due to tiered pricing.

Here's what I have done so far.

First, under `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Tier Price > Frontend Properties` I have set `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` to **Yes** in order to use the `tier_price` attribute to create Shopping Cart Price Rules.

Second, I have set conditions in my Shopping Cart Price Rule which should prevent applying the coupon to two or more units of an item with tiered pricing.

Please find a screen shot of my current condition settings below.

[image: Magento Shopping Cart Price Rule and Tier Price]

The problem is that the use of the coupon is allowed by the system even when I put 2 or more units of a tier priced item in the shopping cart.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and what do you have in your actions tab?

Comment: Hi Negin, I don't have anything in my actions tab

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the application of the coupon based on the items in the cart in the actions tab.

Below the second heading on that tab you can select the sku's for which you want the coupon to be applicable.

The conditions should then consist of:
All sku's that don't have tiered pricing
All sku's that do have tiered pricing with the added condition 
"quantity in cart [equals or less than] 1"
That way the coupon only applies to all products except those with tiered pricing where more than 1 is in the shopping cart.